# Meltano Kafka Monk.io integration

Tags: apache-kafka, etl, message-queue, meltano

I'm playing a bit with Monk.io and Kafka - Meltano integration.
So, I would like to create a Monk.io Kafka cluster and provision a new connection on Meltano.
I'm using https://github.com/lensesio/fast-data-dev for Kafka env.
What would be the best approach and have the most sense?
I've planed to do it this way:
Create runnables of Kafka and Meltano and create Monk actions for Meltano template.
Those actions would have custom Meltano loader that would provide pipe to Kafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested the integration with Kafka but should be similar to Postgres in terms of execution in actions i.e to add a loader or extractor if those Kafka plugins exist for Meltano.

```
  actions:
    defines: actions
    add:
      arguments:
        resource-type:
          type: string
        resource-name:
          type: string
      code: exec("meltano", "/bin/sh", "-c", `cd elt && meltano add ${args["resource-type"]} ${args["resource-name"]}`)
```

The workflow and template are abstracted here https://github.com/monk-io/monk-dataops so it's more a question if Meltano has a good Kafka plugin